# How can i check if a URL exists via Guile Scheme?

Tags: http, scheme, lisp, guile

I tried to google my question before but i didn't found anything about how to check if a URL http status code is 404 or not by using scheme, so forgive me if my question can sound a little bit foreseen.

Comment: If you can use Chicken i recommend installing this [https-client egg](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/http-client)

Comment: For guile, [these modules](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Web.html#Web) probably have a way to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

From the [web modules](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Web.html), use the `(web response)` and `(web client)` modules:

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (use-modules (web client))
scheme@(guile-user)> (use-modules (web response))
scheme@(guile-user)> (response-code (http-request "http://www.example.org"))
$3 = 200
```

Note that if the host name cannot be resolved, this will signal an error.